# Messed up source code in mediawiki template source

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

Just started with media wiki but i have a weird problem.

I want to copy a simple template "Template:Note" so i visit:

[Mediawiki template link](http://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Template%3aNote&action=edit)

the code of the template that it shows to my browser is:

```
{{#if: {{{1|}}}|<div class="block-note"><span class="block-contents">|
    [[File:Bulbgraph.png|18px|Note|link=]]}} '''Note:''' {{#if: {{{1|}}}|{{{1}}}</span></div>}}
```

No i havent copied pasted wrong, this is what it shows. The syntax is wrong ..| is in the wrong places and general the syntax is not correct. Of course it doesnt work if i copy paste, i have to manually correct the syntax.

This happens if i try to export it from the special pages.

Why this is happening?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that code, I think it's correct.

Comment: No its not, Look at the pipes character spread all over..If you take a look at winter's documentation about the if directive you'll see

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the pipes. There are two pipes for each `#if` (separating condition, yes-path and no-path) and one pipe for each argument reference in the conditions (to make sure the condition evaluates for an empty string when no argument was given).

Comment: the documentation for #if says: `{{#if | bool || evaluate & return if true || evaluate & return if false }}`. Why i have : after if. the first pipe should be after {{{1}}} and then double pipe after the true and false conditions.. What am i missing guys?

Comment: Link: [http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Winter/Documentation#.23if] (Winter Documentation)

Comment: @e4rthdog, but the code you posted doesn't use Winter, it's using [ParserFunctions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions). As far as I know, Wikimedia wikis don't use Winter.

Comment: ops! since i have winter on my wiki BUT also parserfunctions, shouldn't it work?

Comment: Suggest you temporarily remove all extensions, then add them one by one, starting with ParserFunctions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [Extension:ParserFunctions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aParserFunctions).

Comment: I just checked and it seems it comes as a standard to 1.19..the problem is that if i use the above code still doesnt work...

Comment: I found this thread after a lot of unproductive experimentation and banging my head on the wall. And, I almost ignored this advice because of the comment that it's "standard". So, I'm chiming in to confirm this is the right answer. ParserFunctions is included in the archive, but is not enabled by default. You still need to enable it, according to the documentation. And, you'll need to add the correct CSS (which I'm trying to figure out how to do now).

Comment: "Standard" means it is included in tarball, you still have to enable it (installer offers you to do this). Some distro-specific packages might not include ParserFunctions at all.